# django form: default initial value

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-templates

I'm now make with django Framework to build the fundraising site.

But, I have some problem on in site.
I maked different class in models.

I want to put in form default value.

```
 {{ form.funding }} ..... -> problem 
 (<input value="{{ funding.price }}">) -> want to same form of this.
```

for details, please see the template.

for example,

models.py

```
class Fundinfo(models.Model):
    price = model.PositiveIntegerField(null= False)

class Funding(models.Model):
    funding = models.PositiveIntegerField(null= False)
    info = models.ForeignKey(Fundinfo)
```

forms.py

```
class FundingForm(forms.models.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Funding
        fields = ('funding', )
```

Template 'funding.html'

```
{% for funding in fundings %}
    <h3>{{ funding.price }}or more</h3>
    <form method= "post" action="">
        {{ form.funding }} ..... -> problem 
        (<input value="{{ funding.price }}">) -> want to same form of this. 
        {% csrf_token %}
    {% if form.errors %}
        <div class = "help-block">{{ form.funding.errors }}</div>
    {% endif %}
    <button id = "" type = "submit">funding</button>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
def view_funding(reqeust, project_id):
     fundings = FundInfo.objects.filter(project= project_id)
     form = PledgeForm() # How to use in here form = FundingForm(initial={'funding': form.funding.price})
     return render(request, 'funding.html', {
    'fundings': info,
    'form': form
    })
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having? I don't see a question here.

Comment: One thing: You wrote `Foriegnkey` which should be `ForeignKey`.

Comment: I want to put default form value. same as form = FundingForm(initial= {'funding': form.funding.price}), but i have to put in template..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give some initial value to form field then use `initial` in your form

```
Class MYform(forms.ModelForm):
    funding = forms.PositiveIntgerField(initial=10)
```

This is the way how u can assign initial value to form